# convert class to dictionary

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

I have a `sqlalchemy` mapped class, and I'd like to convert it to a python dict, for the purpose of returning the object from flask via jsonify. In other words I'd like to do away with the `to_map` function in the code below:

```
def to_map(user):
    m = {}
    m['id'] = user.id
    m['name'] = user.name
    return m

@app.route("/users.json")
def some_route_function()
    users = [to_map(user) for user in User.query.all()]
    return flask.jsonify({'users': users})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick one-liner would be

```
{ key: getattr(user, key) for key in dir(user) if not key.startswith('_') }
```

Which works on the convention/assumption that anything starting with an underscore is private.

Answer (score 1):

There is `__table__` class attribute in sqlalchemy models, you can use it:

```
[{c.name: getattr(user, c.name) for c in User.__table__.columns}
                                for user in User.query.all()]
```

Comment: My answer was based on the Python that I know since I've never used sqlalchemy, but yours is probably better for the tools at hand.